# What is the difference between canvas.width and canvas.clientWidth

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, three.js

I am learning three.js and in one example, the author creates a canvas element and then binds the renderer to that canvas element.

```
 <canvas id="c">
 </canvas>

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
```

Then he gets the canvas element and stores it to a variable with `canvas = renderer.domElement;`

What is the difference between `canvas.width` and `canvas.clientWidth`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference comes from the [HTMLCanvasElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement) (`<canvas/>`) specification. The `width` property is specific to HTMLCanvasElement, and represents "number of logical pixels" *stored by* one row of the canvas. On the other hand, the `clientWidth` property is [common to all Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) and represents the number of pixels horizontally *occupied by* the canvas. These need not be the same — for example, it's common to draw into a canvas at higher or lower resolution than the space it occupies on the page, in order to improve performance or to support a [devicePixelRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) >1, such as a high-density display.

Comment: An other common case is a detached canvas.